# Whole JSONObject sent as JSON key using HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: java, android, json, node.js, httpurlconnection

I want to send a POST request to my NodeJS/Express API with some JSON data. I managed to make GET requests with no problem. Here's what I do for a POST request:

```
URL u = new URL(url);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("nombre", "testing");
c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(),"UTF-8").length()));
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
c.setUseCaches(false);
c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
c.setConnectTimeout(0);
c.setReadTimeout(0);
c.connect();

DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream ());
printout.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(),"UTF-8"));
printout.flush ();
printout.close ();

int status = c.getResponseCode();
```

In my API, I have a `console.log(req.body);` to see what is my POST route getting, and this is what I get in my console:

```
Got this for POST: 
{ '{"nombre":"testing"}': '' }
```

The whole JSONObject is sent as the key for the JSON object with an empty value on the HTTP POST request. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If want to send some more complex try retrofit and gson. It is much easier than httpurlconnection and org.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace

```
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

with

```
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

and

```
printout.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(),"UTF-8"));
```

with

```
printout.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: Worked great! Just needed to change the following line to match the Content-length of the JSON I am sending. Thanks! c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString(requestBody.toString().length()));